# Typescript typings for parent/child class methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm creating mini orm in my pet-project. Trying to do models usable in IDE and compiler, but stuck with typing problems.

I have base model class:

```
import { db } from '../db/db';

export interface Criteria<T> {
  field: Extract<keyof T, string>;
  value: T[Extract<keyof T, string>];
  comparison?: string;
}

export class BaseModel {
  static _pk = 'id';

  static _table: string = null;

  constructor(params: object) {
    for (const key in params) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(params, key)) {
        const fn = `${key}Process`;
        if (typeof this[fn] === 'function') {
          this[fn](params[key]);
        } else {
          this[key] = params[key];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  create<T extends typeof BaseModel>(this: T): Promise<InstanceType<T>> {
    const params = this._getParams(); //TS2339: Property '_getParams' does not exist on type 'T'.
    const thisTyped = this.constructor as T;
    return db
      .insertFromModel(thisTyped._table, params)
      .then((id) => thisTyped.findOne([{ field: thisTyped._pk, value: id }])); //TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Extract<keyof InstanceType<T>, string>'.
  }

  static findOne<T extends typeof BaseModel>(this: T, criteria: Criteria<InstanceType<T>>[]): Promise<InstanceType<T>> {
    return db.selectFromModel(this._table, criteria, true).then((row: object) => {
      return new this(row) as InstanceType<T>;
    });
  }

  _getParams() {
    const params = {};
    for (const key of Object.keys(this)) {
      if (['id', '_table', '_pk'].includes(key)) {
        continue;
      } else {
        params[key] = this[key];
      }
    }
    return params;
  }
}
```

And child class:

```
import { BaseModel } from './BaseModel';
export class User extends BaseModel {
  static _table = 'users';

  static _pk = 'id';

  id: number;

  email: string;

  password: string;

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-useless-constructor
  constructor(props: { id?: number; email: string; password: string }) {
    super(props);
  }
}
```

static method from base class works good, but after adding **create** method I'm getting error while compile... Errors described in comments in code.

One more error could be achieved with code:

```
new User({ email: 'test@test.com', password: '123123' }).create().then((user) => {//TS2684: The 'this' context of type 'User' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'typeof BaseModel'.   Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof BaseModel': prototype, _pk, _table, findOne, and 2 more
  console.log(user);
});
```

Don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I do all in analogy with static method.

Also full code for experiments available here - https://github.com/kricha/ts_q

thanks.

Comment: Criteria interface should enforce that the value match its field, no?

Comment: @vera. in my case it need to autocomplete/check field value, value value could be even just string